# Android getResources from different class

Tags: android, resources, bitmap

I have two classes, Class A called Apply and Class B called Option
I want class A to get a resource from class B, but I'm getting error

the error I'm getting

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type ContextWrapper
```

the function on class A

```
public static void applyBitmap(int resourceID) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inScaled = true;
    opt.inPurgeable = true;
    opt.inInputShareable = true;
    Bitmap brightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceID, opt);
    brightBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(brightBitmap, 100, 100, false);
    MyBitmap = brightBitmap;

}
```

and example of a resource button in class B

```
    // the 34th button
    Button tf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tFour);
    tf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Apply.applyBitmap(R.drawable.tFour);

        }
    });
```

note*: before when the function was on class B in was working great, but know I think I need to static the resource but how ? I don't know

I tried `Option.getResources()` but it didn't work, it gives an error

Comment: What if you erase the " static" from class A? Do you need it static? Actually its a java fundamental understanding. I humbly suggest you to re-read java fundamentals.

Comment: Yoi declared this : public static void applyBitmap(int resourceID)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `getResources()` without a reference to a `Context`. Because this is a static method, you can only access other static methods within that class without providing a reference.

Instead, you must pass the `Context` as an argument:

```
// the 34th button
Button tf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tFour);
tf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Apply.applyBitmap(v.getContext(), R.drawable.tFour); // Pass your context to the static method
    }
});
```

Then, you must reference it for `getResources()`:

```
public static void applyBitmap(Context context, int resourceID) {
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inScaled = true;
    opt.inPurgeable = true;
    opt.inInputShareable = true;
    Bitmap brightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resourceID, opt); // Use the passed context to access resources
    brightBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(brightBitmap, 100, 100, false);
    MyBitmap = brightBitmap;
}
```